# Why did Greer sacrifice himself?

Tags: person-of-interest

In one particular episode, Greer locks himself and Finch into a room, and tells him that he was performing the 'Queen's sacrifice' to ensure the victory of Samaritan. Then the air gets sucked out of the room, and Greer dies of asphyxiation. Harold is saved by the Machine. Why didn't Greer simply asphyxiate Finch alone? Why did he have to kill himself too?

Answer (score 3):

Because any attempt to preserve his life may give opening for Finch to escape. Notice that they're alone at that moment. Also, he is a true believer in Samaritan. SO he considered it a worthy sacrifice.

Comment: Maybe also because Greer and Finch are the only two people in the world capable of somehow tampering with Samaritan or obstructing its work.

Comment: I don't believe that. Neither is capable of somehow tampering with Samaritan. Well, maybe Finch - but only through The Machine. Greer said it himself: gambit, sacrificing the queen. Also, any attempt to eliminate Finch prematurely could mean Samaritan's destruction (by releasing the virus by the machine) and did not guarantee success in eliminating The Machine. So Greer played the role of a bait and a tranquilizer in one: to pull Finch in where he could be killed without the Machine knowing and lulling Finch to think he's not to be killed yet.